# Cron which java -jar does not work

Tags: bash, 20.04, java, cron, error-handling

I have a cron job which runs bash.sh file. If I run the file in terminal it works fine. But as I try to run it as cron job something happened there and I cant figure out what. Cron job looks like:

```
*/5 * * * * bash /home/vlado/custom-scripts/selenium-server/run-selenium-hub-and-nodes.sh 2>> /var/log/cron/selenium-server.log
```

and run-selenium-hub-and-nodes.sh is here

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /opt/selenium-server/

# -c returns number of lines in grep result
countHub=$(ps -x | grep -v "grep" | grep "selenium-server" | grep "role hub" -c)
countNodes=$(ps -x | grep -v "grep" | grep "selenium-server" | grep "role node" -c) 


# if selenium server HUB is in ps -x result
if [ $countHub -eq 1 ] 
then 


  # if there is NO NODE
  if [ $countNodes -eq 0 ] 
  then 
    
    # start two new nodes
    java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://173.249.58.30:4444/grid/register/ & 
    java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://173.249.58.30:4444/grid/register/ & 
    exit 0    
  
  # if there is only ONE NODE
  elif [ $countNodes -eq 1 ] 
  then 
  
    # start one new node
    java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://173.249.58.30:4444/grid/register/ & 
    exit 0
    
  fi  
    

else # if there is NO HUB start new hub and two new nodes

  # kill all possible hubs and nodes for sure
  pkill -9 -f "selenium-server"

  # Start new hub
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub & 
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://173.249.58.30:4444/grid/register/ & 
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://173.249.58.30:4444/grid/register/ & 
  exit 0

fi
```

I can see in syslog the script is running and try to send an email. I installed postfix because of it, but I am not able to see the message. There is no more info in syslog file. Is there any other log for which collects more informations about cron jobs? After few hours I made a decision to ask the question. Thanks for help.

Comment: Jobs run through `cron`, `crontab`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`). 
  
One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
 Read `man 5 crontab`.
  
Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments

Comment: You don't need to install a mail agent to see cron output. Look up how to *redirect cron output* to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution use the full path to java to have it work. As has been mentioned in the comment nothing get carried into the crontab from the users settings. You need to do it all yourself by setting these things manually.

Comment: Ok I am going to try it.

Comment: Yes it works, Thanks a lot.  Now I have a problem with pkill. It seems it kills whole process and next commands are not executed after pkill call. What is it?

Comment: No idea, but I can tell you the command is not necessary. You have already tested for nodes and there was none for it to find, to make it to that point in the script, you just need to execute your commands then. By the way why two identical start commands with the -node argument there for three commands total.

Comment: It crates two nodes. Hub delegates tests to this two nodes. May be I am wrong I saw it to do so.

Comment: If it works like this then continue to use it, I was just thinking the duplicate was unnecessary or it may error on you doing it that way.

Comment: Now it enters my head, you want a greater than 2 test then the pkill command can be used in that instance. Plus an equal to 2 test where the script just exits as the program has the two nodes you seek already running. It will then exit the script on the pkill for the next run where it will start up the nodes, on an equal to two it will exit leaving your two running nodes plus still do what you want with the first two test you have. You will then have complete script covering all the options needed.

Comment: I can have max two nodes because of RAM on the server. It opens about 10 Chrome browsers in parallel so it could slow down the server if there will be more than two nodes.

Comment: And the problem with pkill was that the script has selenium-server string in the path so it killed itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120152/discussion-between-happytux-and-camo).